# How to make html table into a responsive design

Tags: html, psd

Below is the Html table derived by converting a PSD file.How to make the HTML table responsive to the devices it's viewed? Now the table's width and height in pixels.Is there a way to use media query or any other way to make the design responsive?

```
<table id="Table_01" width="1340" height="754" border="0" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0">
    <tr>
        <td colspan="12">
            <img src="images/superstar_01.png" width="1339" height="28" alt=""></td>
        <td>
            <img src="images/spacer.gif" width="1" height="28" alt=""></td>
    </tr>
<tr>.....................
</tr>
</table>
```

Comment: Tables are used for tabular data not for website designs :) Try first to write html code with DIV:s etc and after that place images.

Answer (score 0):

well, the first step would be not to convert a psd file into HTML.
the @media rule from css styling allows you to make css rules that only apply to certain media sizes, or ranges of sizes, so that would be the start.

http://www.w3schools.com/css/css_mediatypes.asp

You might want to invest in learning css, it's a completely different way of styling than photoshop and if you're going to do front-end web development yourself you'll need to learn how it works.

Comment: Thanks @serakfalcon..I believe instead of converting into HTML from PSD, I should use css to style it in % from Pixels.In that way I can use div instead of table?Will this work for responsive site?

Comment: Yes. There are many ways to do responsive, one way is to allow the DIV's to 'flow' freely, so on a big screen you will have several per row and on a small screen, they'll be the width of the screen another is to resize them based on the media size or by making them a fixed % (note that things can only be % size OR px size, not both, so something that takes up 25% of the screen on a big screen may not be legible on a mobile phone, though you can set min-width).
Div's are better than tables since they have less 'side-effects' and are more flexible.

Comment: Almost all websites  use div's as the main 'workhorse' structural elements.